# How can I get all Excel ribbons tab ids and labels?

Tags: c#, excel-addins, ribbonx

I am working on an Excel add-in tool with a custom ribbon implementation. For this I need to find existing Excel ribbon tab ids and labels in Excel. How can I do this in C#?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Globals class to access the Ribbon:

```
foreach (Ribbon ribbon in Globals.Ribbons)
{
    // do something here
}
```

Refer: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bhczd18c.aspx

A ribbon inherits from a `RibbonBase` class, which doesn't have an ID property as part of the object model, but does use a Name or RibbonID property as unique attributes.

More at: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.ribbon.ribbonbase(v=vs.120).aspx